# JasperReport exporting to xlsx format works fine with java code but not with jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I am working on a complex report structure with jasper report studio. Everything was fine until I publish the report on jasper server. I am not getting the same output when exporting to xlsx format.

This is the xlsx format generated by `JRXlsxExporter` class [image]

And this what i am getting from jasper server export to xlsx format [image]

Comment: Do you use the same JR version on server and local ?

Comment: @SEY_91 Probably styles and fonts are not deployed right on JRS. What is a difference in two versions?

Comment: I am using jasperreports 6.1.0 on local and jasperreports-server-cp-6.3.0 on server. I will try to use the same version maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the property `collapseRowSpan` to `false` of the bean `xlsExportParameters` declared in the `/jasperreports-server-cp-6.3.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INFapplicationContext.xml` file the xlsx export works fine just like expected.